# “ProgrammingError at / relation ”posts_post“ does not exist LINE 1: …evious_post_id”, “posts_post”.“next_post_id” FROM “posts_pos…”

Tags: python, django, postgresql, nginx, django-models

I just finished writing a blog app with django which works perfectly locally but on deploying, I'm getting this error "OperationalError at / no such table: posts_post". After installing postgres, the error message changed to "ProgrammingError at / relation "posts_post" does not exist LINE 1: ...evious_post_id", "posts_post"."next_post_id" FROM "posts_pos..." Please what can I do?

Like if I am trying to deploy a new project from the beginning I am able to do that without any error but when I try to deploy my already existing project which works fine on my local windows machine with Postgres DB it fails to migrate the data and pops error that relation "posts_post does not exist". Below one can find the attached screenshot of the error.
Please let me know that if it's possible to deploy a full-fledged Django web app with all the data prepared on localhost(using Django admin) using Postgres DB on Linux.
[image]

Comment: Share your view where you retrieve this error, together with the full traceback.

Comment: Are you sure the settings are correct: did you set the correct SQL "dialect"?

Comment: did you do migration after changing the database?

Comment: can you show us some of your code? its hard to find a solution based on only the error message

Comment: please, you must do python migrate because you not have table

Comment: that is the error message popped when I tried to run "python manage.py makemigrations"

Answer (score 0):

Everytime you change you model or moveto different/new datastore you need to run
migrations
`python manage.py makemigrations`
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/migrations/

Comment: the error comes when I run the command itself